# Scraping Wikipedia for information with Beautiful Soup

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I managed to scrape wikipedia for names of US Presidents using Beautiful Soup. After which I converted them into dataframe.

```
names=[all the president's name]
wiki =[url of the president's wiki page]
combine = {'name':names,'wiki_url':wiki}
df = pd.DataFrame(combine)
df.index.name='id'
display(df)

id  name                 wiki_url                       father       mother
0   George Washington   /wiki/George_Washington
1   John Adams          /wiki/John_Adams
2   Thomas Jefferson    /wiki/Thomas_Jefferson
```

How do I scrape through each president entry and update the dataframe with their father's and mother's names using Beautiful Soup?

I know for each page, there's the html <table class='infobox vcard", which contains the Father's and Mother's name?

Comment: Wikipedia has an API. Why use web scraping?

Comment: Besides the Wikipedia API, it might be worthwhile to look at Wikidata, where most of the information is already held in a structured format.

Comment: because my assignments required me to use Beautiful Soup for scraping. Not allowed to use the API

Comment: @zeerock how do you determine the president's father's and mother's name? - I don't see any of those values on wikipedia....

Answer (score 0):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

r = requests.get('https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/George_Washington').text
s = BeautifulSoup(r, 'lxml')
for th in s.find_all('th', class_='infobox-label'):
    if th.text == "Parent(s)":
        td = th.next_sibling
        for a in td.find_all('a'):
            print(a.text)
```